# Laravel Yajra Datatable Service using Array Object

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

i would like to use object array instead of query for my datatable and it is not working because it's not from query collection.

my array just like this

```
public function query(){
    $santri = DataSantri::select('data_santri.*','id_vc')
                            ->join('vc','data_santri.id_user','=','vc.id_user')
                            ->whereIn('status_kegiatan',['ziyadah','mutqin','tahsin'])
                            ->get();
    foreach($santri as $row){
        $pl = PaymentList::where('is_active',1)
                           ->where('angkatan',$row->angkatan)
                           ->where('payment_list.payment_time','bulanan')
                           ->get();
        $totalPl = DB::table('payment_list')
                                ->where('is_active',1)
                                ->where('angkatan',$row->angkatan)
                                ->where('payment_list.payment_time','bulanan')
                                ->sum('payment_price');
        $pa = PaymentAddon::where('nis',$row->nis)->get();
        $totalPa = DB::table('payment_addon')
                                    ->where('nis',$row->nis)
                                    ->sum('payment_price');
        $data[] =  array(
            'nis' => $row->nis,
            'id_vc' => $row->id_vc,
            'nama_lengkap_santri' => $row->nama_lengkap_santri,
            'jk' => $row->jk_santri,
            'data_pembayaran_bulanan' => $pl,
            'data_pembayaran_tambahan' => $pa,
            'total' => $totalPl + $totalPa
        );
    }
    $collect = collect($data);
    return $this->applyScopes($collect);

}
```

it returns error like this

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getQuery does not exist.
```

how can i solve this error? thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post ques. in detail means how are you using Yajra datatable and all.

Datatable takes data in object format and you are providing in array format so please change it to object.

```
public function query(){
$santri = DataSantri::select('data_santri.*','id_vc')
                        ->join('vc','data_santri.id_user','=','vc.id_user')
                        ->whereIn('status_kegiatan',['ziyadah','mutqin','tahsin'])
                        ->get();
$data = []; // initialize empty array
foreach($santri as $row){
    $pl = PaymentList::where('is_active',1)
                       ->where('angkatan',$row->angkatan)
                       ->where('payment_list.payment_time','bulanan')
                       ->get();
    $totalPl = DB::table('payment_list')
                            ->where('is_active',1)
                            ->where('angkatan',$row->angkatan)
                            ->where('payment_list.payment_time','bulanan')
                            ->sum('payment_price');
    $pa = PaymentAddon::where('nis',$row->nis)->get();
    $totalPa = DB::table('payment_addon')
                                ->where('nis',$row->nis)
                                ->sum('payment_price');
    $data[] =  (object) array(
        'nis' => $row->nis,
        'id_vc' => $row->id_vc,
        'nama_lengkap_santri' => $row->nama_lengkap_santri,
        'jk' => $row->jk_santri,
        'data_pembayaran_bulanan' => $pl,
        'data_pembayaran_tambahan' => $pa,
        'total' => $totalPl + $totalPa
    );
}

return $this->applyScopes($data);
}
```

Hope this help. If this does't work then revert me so i will tell you the best way to use datatable using **Yajra**